# SELECT Query for multiple columns

Tags: sql

I'm not very skilled at SQL and need some help. I have a table with many columns and am trying to identify those rows where multiple combinations of column values are the same. Below is a try at a query that would select the row when ALL comparisons were true. The query runs but not with the correct effect.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Customer] 
WHERE [State] = [Shipping State/Province] 
  AND [Zip Code] = [Shipping Zip/Postal Code] 
  AND [Customer Type] = [Customer Type 2]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can provide a sample data, it will be easy to assist you.

Comment: You have tagged the question MySQL and Postgres.  Yet, neither of these support square braces.  Please tag your question with the database you are really using.  In the meantime, I'm removing the extraneous tags.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

As written, your query would appear to do what you want.  One possibility is that `NULL` values are ignored.  If so:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Customer]
WHERE ([State] = [Shipping State/Province] OR [State] IS NULL AND [Shipping State/Province] IS NULL) AND
      ([Zip Code] = [Shipping Zip/Postal Code] OR [Zip Code] IS NULL AND [Shipping Zip/Postal Code] IS NULL) AND
      ([Customer Type] = [Customer Type 2] OR [Customer Type] IS NULL AND [Customer Type 2] IS NULL);
```

Another possibility is that values may look the same, but because of leading/trailing spaces or similar looking letters, they are not.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in casting. If your column type is integer then dividing its value by another column will give you integer part of division which may not be equal to your result so your query will not give correct answer.
for resolution you can cast you column type and do calculation.

Comment: `[Shipping Zip/Postal Code]` Here division will not happen it is a column name. Check it is enclosed with *square brackets*. Answer is simply irrelevant to question